# Github Pages showing posts with future date

Tags: github, jekyll

I have number of posts on `_posts`. Post file have pattern like below

```
├── _posts
│   ├── 2016-10-02-SomeContent.md
│   ├── 2016-10-03-AnotherContent.md
```

On my local machine (ubuntu 16.04 LTS) If I prefix my `post file` name which **`future date`** like `2017-10-03-FutureContent.md` the post with future date prefixed is not shown.

I'm using `bundle exec jekyll serve` to run the project

But when I push it to `Github` it's visible and shows the posted date as future date.

[Using this theme](https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll)

Why can't I see the post on my local machine but when pushed to Github it is visible?

Comment: Could it be a time zone difference?

Comment: I configured timezone on config file. I guess both local and github will use same timezone if specified on config file

Comment: What version of Jekyll are you using?

Answer (score 4):

You should serve with:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --future
```

The reason why it's available on GitHub is because: [GitHub's pages-gem enables the `future` flag](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/blob/master/lib/github-pages/configuration.rb#L18)